# Download a PDF file to internal storage using AsyncTask in Android

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, internal-storage

I'm looking for a way to download a PDF file to internal storage using threading like AsyncTask. I searched on the internet for but I couldn't find a good tutorial. Can anyone show me how to do this with an example?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an excellent post that discussed how to use `AsyncTask` to download a large file, as well as to show the progress of the download by using `ProgressDialog`: [Download a file with Android, and showing the progress in a ProgressDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028306/download-a-file-with-android-and-showing-the-progress-in-a-progressdialog)

Answer (score 0):

The best and simple way to download a file in android is using DownloadManager class. See [this tutorial](http://blog.vogella.com/2011/06/14/android-downloadmanager-example/) for understanding how to use this class.